# Getting following error when testing the trained python model

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Please help me through this..

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "object_detection\legacy\train.py", line 186, in 
tf.app.run()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
_run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
_run_main(main, args)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "object_detection\legacy\train.py", line 110, in main
overwrite=True)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 469, in copy
copy_v2(oldpath, newpath, overwrite)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 486, in copy_v2
compat.as_bytes(src), compat.as_bytes(dst), overwrite)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open:  : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now your question is very unclear. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources exist to help you have a good experience here, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: As the error clearly says in the last line, it is the error with the paths specified, If you have trained the model from different system then try to change the path in the current system accordingly.